# Find indices within a string where any combination of an array of words is found

Tags: javascript

Sample data:
String: "barfoofoobarthefoobarman"
Array of words: ["bar", "foo", "the"]

Output:
[6, 9, 12]

I was asked this question during an interview. Due to time constraint, I tried to find all the possible words that could be made out of the array of words (i. e. "barfoothe"), but was told that would not scale for large arrays. Was suggested to use a map data structure, but I think my solution doesn't scale either, and it's brute forced.

Here's the solution.

```js
var solution = function(string, words) {
    let output = [];
    let wordsMap = new Map();
    let wordsNumber = words.length;
    let wordLength = words[0].length;
    words.forEach((word) => {
        if (!wordsMap.has(word))
            wordsMap.set(word, 1);
        else
            wordsMap.set(word, wordsMap.get(word) + 1);
    });        
 
    for (let i = 0; i <= string.length-(wordsNumber*wordLength); i+=wordLength) {
        let tempMap = new Map(wordsMap);
        let check = true;
        let tempString = string.substring(i, i + wordsNumber*wordLength);
        for (let j = 0; j <= tempString.length - wordLength; j += wordLength) {
            let tempString2 = tempString.substring(j, j + wordLength);
            if (tempMap.has(tempString2))
                tempMap.set(tempString2, tempMap.get(tempString2) - 1);
        }
        for (let val of tempMap.values()){
            if (val !== 0){
                check = false
                break;
            }
        }
        
        if (check)
            output.push(i)
    }
    console.log(output);        
}

solution("barfoothefoobarman", ["foo", "bar"]);
```

Any suggestion for a smarter solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dynamic regular expression.

```js
const words = ['foo', 'bar']
const rx = new RegExp(words.join('|'), 'g') 
// todo escape special characters
```

Then search away.

```js
const counts = words.map(it=>0) // [0,0]
// todo use map or object to track counts instead of array
while (m = rx.exec(inputString)) {
  const index = words.indexOf(m[0])
  counts[index]++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your question. I think the question in the interview was less about the right solution and more about the right approach.

The trickiest part is actually just finding the word combinations. There are several approaches here. For me it's a clear case for recursion.

So my approach would be:

1. find all word combinations, except combinations with itself (for example: foofoo or barbar).
2. iterate through the word combinations and ask whether they are contained in the string.
3. extra: Sort SolutionArray
   Done!

**Note:** I use indexOf() for point 2 but I think a regex match would make it even better because you find all possibilities of a word in a string and not just the first one like with indexOf. Would make sense for longer strings.

```js
    const arr = ["foo", "bar"];
    const str = "barfoothefoobarman" 
    let res = [];
    const combinations = (len, val, existing) => {    
       if (len == 0) {
          res.push(val);
          return;
       }
      
       for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
          if(! existing[i]) {
             existing[i] = true;
             combinations(len-1, val + arr[i], existing);         
             existing[i] = false;
          } 
       }
    }

    const buildCombinations = (arr = []) => {
       for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          combinations(arr.length - i, "", []);      
       }
    };

    buildCombinations(arr);

    // exclude the base wordes from result array
    newRes = res.filter((e) => {  
      if (! arr.includes(e)) {    
        return e;
      } 
    })
    
    console.log('all word combinations:', newRes);

    // get the string position
    const _positions = [];
    newRes.forEach((w) => {
      let res = str.indexOf(w);      
      if (res != -1 && ! _positions.includes(res)) {
          _positions.push(res);  
      }  
    })

    // sort array and use Float64Array to speed up
    const positions = new Float64Array(_positions)
    console.log('positions', positions.sort())
```